# Date conversion for YY-Monthtext to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Receive date as `"19-May"` and need to convert it as `'05/01/2019'`, `"19-June"` to `'06/01/2019'`.

I have tried various date conversion but it didn't work.

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: Are you sure about `"June"`? I think it's `"Jun"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Storing date in this format is not a good/suggestion you should use the proper data type which are meant and available for.

You should update the values with proper date time value and then change the data type also. It will save your time & you do not need these conversions every time.

```
Select Try_Cast('19-May 2019' as Datetime)
```

OR

```
Select Try_Cast('19-May' + '2019' as Datetime)
```

To get the first date of month you can try the below query.

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, Try_Cast('19-May 2019' as Datetime)), 0) AS StartOfMonth
```

**Edit**

To get the first date of month as per the given data in string, you can use the below query.

```
declare @dateinStr varchar(20) = '19-May'
Select try_cast('01-' + Replace(@dateinStr, LEFT(@dateinStr, 3), '') + LEFT(@dateinStr, 2) as Datetime) as Date
```

Here is the [demo](https://rextester.com/RTH85559).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the months will be 3 chars only, if so then

```
Select s,
       try_Cast(concat(right(s, 3), ' 2019') as Datetime)
from
(
    values
    ('19-May'),
    ('19-Jun')
) t(s);
```

If the months is really comes like "June" & "August" then

```
select s, 
       try_cast(concat(substring(s, charindex('-',s)+1, 3), ' 2019') as date)
from
(
    values
    ('19-May'),
    ('19-June'),
    ('15-August')
) t(s);
```

If you need to format it as `mm/dd/yyyy` then use `101` style.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(CONVERT(DATE, Dates + '-2019'), -1))
FROM ( VALUES ('19-May'), ('19-June') 
     ) t(Dates);
```